# how to add files to depot as writible (perforce )

Tags: perforce

Hello ı have a problem with perforce , I am student and my projects submitted to perforce depot,  but  the files that ı add become read-only and my porject connot build beacuse its read only properties, How can ı add files to depot as writible

Answer (score 1):

For files that have already been submitted to the depot, you can open them for edit, and then right click in P4V and choose "Change filetype" from the context menu. If you add the +w modifier, the files will always be writeable on the client.

When you're adding new files to the depot, you should change the file type before submitting the initial add.

If you're using the command line to add and edit files, you can specify the file type with the -t flag in both the [add](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_add.html) and [edit](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_edit.html) commands.

Before you start marking files as writeable, though, I would make sure that they belong in the depot in the first place. Things like intermediate object files and whatnot are usually not checked in because of the problems they will cause if they're read only.

Comment: Another technique is to set your workspace as "allwrite". But definitely check on the files that were submitted; it sounds like things like .class files and their jars were submitted, rather than just the java source code (or the equivalent for another language).

Comment: Yeah that would definitely work as well. For people more used to a Git workflow that's probably more natural, but I actually like things being read-only unless they're checked out.